# What happens to the board if you connect the +5V pin directly to a digital input configured as input

Tags: arduino-uno

I have maybe a very stupid question but connecting the +5V pin to a digital input pin programmed as input ( let's say pin2) . Will it destroy the board? Cause after i did this my board doesn't work anymore and i can also not upload a sketch to it. it does nothing anymore, yet nothing has burned or no smoke.

??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will it destroy the board?

No, it will just read HIGH. That's what HIGH is - 5V.

> Cause after i did this my board doesn't work anymore

Then you probably did *something else*.

Comment: OK. in that case, what happens if you would add +5V from an external supply that is also powering the arduino by +12V . Meaning connecting +12V to Vin and 0V to Ground and than connecting a +5V to an input pin? Cause one way or another i fried these boards but i just don't understand how. I managed to break 2

Comment: Ok. I just measured. I have feeded +12V to the digital pin set as input. So will this frie the board irreperably or can i get the board to work again by replacing a part?

Comment: You may be able to replace the main mcu

Comment: Yes, if you feed +12V into an input pin you will likely damage or destroy the board. I did this with 9V on an Arduino Mega 2560 and it only destroyed that one input pin. The higher the voltage, the more likely it is to damage something, and the more severe that damage is going to be.